# vim7.3 on windows XP: can't set vim as default file type for .cpp/.h files

Tags: windows, vim

I've tried the usual process.

- Open Properties of a file of the type I want to change
- Select the "Change" button after "Opens With":
- Browse to C:\Program Files\vim\vim73\gvim.exe
- Select OK

What I expect to happen: Vim should appear in the "Other Programs" list

What happens: Vim does not appear anywhere in the list, the first choice on the list (notepad) is still selected.

Some advice I saw online indicated that I should add a registry entry that the installer missed. So I added "C:\Program Files\vim\vim73\gvim.exe" "%1" to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\gvim.exe\shell\open\command]. This didn't seem to help.

Any idea what I'm missing here.

EDIT: well, this is interesting. I can set vim.exe to be the default application, just not gvim.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to associate your favourite editor with a given file type
by means of command line tools instead of hacking the registry.

First, check if there is already a file type associated with the given extension, e.g. with `.txt`

```
C:\Temp> assoc | findstr \.txt
```

The result will be something like this

```
.txt=txtfile
```

Now tell Windows to open files of this type with GVim

```
 C:\Temp> ftype txtfile="C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\gvim.exe" --remote-silent "%1"
```

The `--remote-silent` option causes GVim to open the file in an already existing instance of GVim (without complaining if there isn't any).

Comment: This is much better than what I ended up doing... switching the answer to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Windows' built-in file type association tools are seriously lacking.  However, there are some great freeware utilities from NirSoft that pick up the slack.  Try [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after doing a fresh install of Vim 7.3.3 from the Cream site. What I did to fix the problem was to uninstall Vim, install Vim 7.3 from vim.sf.net, then upgrade to 7.3.3 from the Cream site. I have only a vague understanding of Windows installers so I can't explain exactly why that worked, but it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah... I seem to have hosed this up somewhat more seriously than that. Even if I back down to vim7.2, gvim still won't associate.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I got it working, but this is ugly. Registry hack

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.cpp] : (Default) : gvim

And then create:
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\gvim\shell\open\command] : (Default) : "C:\Program Files\vim\vim73\gvim.exe" "%1"